# Why Django template loader is case-sensitive in production but not in development

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I'm using `manage.py runserver` on a MacOs Catalina OS as development. I have some templates that fit my built-in class based views. For example:

```
CuadroDeControl_detail.html                     LoteDeMedio_list.html                           TipoDeMedio_detail_tablaCuadros.html
CuadroDeControl_detail_resumen.html             LoteDeMedio_list_tabla.html                     TipoDeMedio_list.html
CuadroDeControl_detail_tablaMetodos.html        MetodoDeControl_detail.html                     TipoDeMedio_list_tabla.html
LoteDeMedio_confirm_delete.html                 MetodoDeControl_detail_resumen.html             dropdown_CuadroDeControl.html
LoteDeMedio_create.html                         TipoDeMedio_confirm_delete.html                 dropwdown_CuadroDeControl.html
LoteDeMedio_detail.html                         TipoDeMedio_detail.html
LoteDeMedio_detail_resumen.html                 TipoDeMedio_detail_resumen.html
```

Here is an example of a working view:

```py
class TipoDeMedioDetailView(AreaCalidadMixin, DashboardMixin,  DetailView):
         model = TipoDeMedio
```

Note that my views do not explicitly set `template_name`. In my production
environment, all my views load just fine. Django's template loader knows that the corresponding template to the view is `TipoDeMedio_detail.html`

However, in my production environment, which is set up with `apache2` and `mod_wsgi` on a Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS x86_64  Linode VM, the template loader fails to load the template of the same view, because it searches for it in all lowercase. Here is an example:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://45.79.4.38/calidad/TipoDeMedio/lista
Django Version: 3.1.6
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
calidad/tipodemedio_list.html
Exception Location: /home/jonatan/django-app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/loader.py, line 47, in select_template
Python Executable:  /home/jonatan/django-app/venv/bin/python
Python Version: 3.8.5
Python Path:    
['/home/jonatan/django-app/mysite',
 '/usr/lib/python38.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.8',
 '/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload',
 '/home/jonatan/django-app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages']
Server time:    Mon, 21 Jun 2021 18:24:19 -0500
```

```
Template-loader postmortem

Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:
django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: /home/jonatan/django-app/mysite/templates/calidad/tipodemedio_list.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/jonatan/django-app/mysite/login/templates/calidad/tipodemedio_list.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/jonatan/django-app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/calidad/tipodemedio_list.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/jonatan/django-app/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/calidad/tipodemedio_list.html (Source does not exist)
```

An easy fix is to manually specify my `template_name` attribute on each of my `CBV` and point to the correct case-sensitive template name (for instance `TipoDeMedio_detail.html`. However, I would really like to avoid that.

I'm just trying to understand what is the root cause of the change in behavior between the environments. It just leads me to believe I will encounter similar problems in other aspects of Django's behavior.

Comment: @AnkitTiwari I had to revert some of your edits. Please don't propose edits to switch from American to Imperial English spelling, or vice versa; the guideline is to leave those alone, as long as they are consistent within a post. Also, probably don't use `code` formatting for things which are not code or file names, etc.

Comment: Hello @tripleee sorry for code part but as per this post https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing if there is a grammatical or spelling mistakes I can edit post.

Comment: Absolutely; that's why I approved most of your changes. Maybe read my feedback again.

Comment: Thank you told me I will pay attention from next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default Apple File System (APFS) is not case sensitive. This means that during development on your Mac, Django was able to find templates even if the filenames used incorrect case.

Now that you have moved to Ubuntu, it uses a case-sensitive file system by default. Django is not able to find the templates if the case is wrong.

Note that the [Django docs for class-based generic views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#generic-views-of-objects) state:

> ... in the absence of an explicit template Django will infer one from the object’s name ... is the lowercased version of the model’s name.

The preferable solution is to rename your templates using lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

MattRowbum pointed out to me APFS isn't case sensitive. I consider this sufficient explanation for the change in behavior.